# How to restore the default settings for the Visual Studio 2010 Configuration Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After some "games" with the Visual Studio Configuration Manager I found that every new C#/VB.NET project I create in my Visual Studio only has the 'x86' solution platform. It should be 'Any CPU', and I should be able to choose x86 or x64 if required. How do I reset these settings for all new projects?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft changed the default for EXE's to x86. Check out this post by Rick Byers:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx

> Here's the list I've been using in our discussions to justify making
>   x86 the default for EXE projects in Visual Studio:
>
> - **Running in two very different modes increases product complexity and the cost of testing**   * Often people don't realize the
>     implications on native-interop of architecture-neutral assemblies.  It
>     means you need to ensure that equivalent 32-bit and 64-bit versions of
>     the native DLLs you depend on are available, and (most significantly)
>     the appropriate one is selected automatically.  This is fairly easy
>     when calling OS APIs due to the OS re-mapping of c:\windows\system32
>     to c:\windows\syswow64 when running in the WOW and extensive testing
>     the OS team does.  But many people who ship native DLLs alongside
>     their managed app get this wrong at first and are surprised then their
>     application blows up on 64-bit systems with an exception about their
>     32-bit DLL being in a bad format.  Also, although it's much rarer than
>     for native-code, pointer-size bugs can still manifest in .NET (eg.
>     assuming IntPtr is the same as Int32, or incorrect marshalling
>     declarations when interopping with native code).   * Also, in addition
>     to the rules you need to know to follow, there's just the issue that
>     you've now really got twice as much code to test.  Eg., there could
>     easily be (and certainly have been many) CLR bugs that reproduce only
>     on one architecture of the CLR, and this applies all the way across
>     the stack (from OS, framework, 3rd-party libraries, to your code).  Of
>     course in an ideal world everyone has done a great job testing both
>     32-bit and 64-bit and you won't see any differences, but in practice
>     for any large application that tends not to be the case, and (at
>     Microsoft at least) we end up duplicating our entire test system for
>     32 and 64-bit and paying a significant ongoing cost to testing and
>     supporting all platforms.   * [Edit: Rico - of CLR and VS performance
>     architect fame - just posted a great blog entry on why Visual Studio
>     will not be a pure 64-bit application anytmie soon]
> - **32-bit tends to be faster anyway**   * When an application can run fine either in 32-bit or 64-bit mode, the 32-bit mode tends to be a
>     little faster.  Larger pointers means more memory and cache
>     consumption, and the number of bytes of CPU cache available is the
>     same for both 32-bit and 64-bit processes.  Of course the WOW layer
>     does add some overhead, but the performance numbers I've seen indicate
>     that in most real-world scenarios running in the WOW is faster than
>     running as a native 64-bit process
> - **Some features aren't avaiable in 64-bit**   * Although we all want to have perfect parity between 32-bit and 64-bit, the reality is that
>     we're not quite there yet.  CLR v2 only supported mixed-mode debugging
>     on x86, and although we've finally added x64 support in CLR V4,
>     edit-and-continue still doesn't support x64.  On the CLR team, we
>     consider x64 to be a first-class citizen whenever we add new
>     functionality, but the reality is that we've got a complicated
>     code-base (eg. completely separate 32-bit and 64-bit JIT compilers)
>     and we sometimes have to make trade-offs (for example, adding 64-bit
>     EnC would have been a very significant cost to the JIT team, and we
>     decided that their time was better spent on higher priority features).
>     There are other cool features outside of the CLR that are also
>     specific to x86 - like historical debugging in VS 2010.  Complicating
>     matters here is that we haven't always done a great job with the error
>     messages, and so sometimes people "upgrade" to a 64-bit OS and are
>     then disgusted to see that some of their features no longer appear to
>     work (without realizing that if they just re-targetted the WOW they'd
>     work fine).  For example, the EnC error in VS isn't very clear
>     ("Changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed"), and has lead to
>     some confusion in practice.  I believe we're doing the right thing in
>     VS2010 and fixing that dialog to make it clear that switching your
>     project to x86 can resolve the issue, but still there's no getting
>     back the time people have wasted on errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the problem? Maybe you should just set "Show Advanced Build Configurations" as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/02/show-advanced-build-configurations-vstipproj0016.aspx).

Comment: Uri, do you think I'm a "very newbie"?? :)  If the "Show advanced build configurations" checkbox were unticked , the "Solution Configuration" and "Solution Platforms" comboboxes would be grayed (disabled) at all!

In my question I meant that "Solution Platforms" contains only one item by default - "x86". It should be "AnyCPU" by default.

Comment: I've looked into c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\WindowsApplication.zip\windowsapplication.csproj. It contains the following:

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
 <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

Shouldn't it be 'AnyCPU'?

Comment: I'm no newvie but run into that problem which took my some time to figure out :)   Did changing the file you've found solved your problem?